# Why does File.Delete() on a directory yield UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

If I call `System.IO.File.Delete()` and pass it a directory name I get `UnauthorizedAccessException` although the problem has nothing to deal with any kind of permissions and I guess `InvalidOperationException` would be much more suitable here.

Why is this specific exception being thrown? Is it a design fault or is there any reason for that?

Comment: You should now treat it as by design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea, but it smells like a design fault because the [Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62t64db3.aspx) has a different behavior that [File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx). Directory.Delete will throw a DirectoryNotFoundException if the path actually refers to a file instead of directory. One would expect that the same kind of exception would be thrown in these two cases.

Comment: In fact: they both rely in the Win32 `GetLastError` API to throw their exceptions. So this is more a Windows thing than a .NET one..

Comment: So not only is the behaviour inconsistent but the reason is because they're exposing the inconsistency of the black box. I can imagine the fun Mono developers had here, trying to mimic the same behaviour for their implementation :-)

Comment: I couldn't be bothered tracing it fully.. but basically theres an internal `__Error` class that is passed the result of `GetLastError` for ~75% of the `File.Delete` and `Directory.Delete` calls. The rest are `IOException`'s ..

Comment: Why should you trace it fully in the first place? If you have to look so deep in the black box to explain an inconsistent behaviour, it smells like bad design of the black box. I'm assuming that the reason this is happening is that the error code is inconsistent from Win32 and fixing that in .NET might be an extra performance penalty (e.g. after receiving that win32 error code, check if the path was a file and not a directory and then throw the proper exception).